# Programatically adjust DataGrid column widths during runtime

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a datatable which is bound to a datagrid upon runtime. How do I programatically adjust the column widths of the datagrid in code?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you have used `AutotGenerateColumns=true` or `DataTable` as ItemsSource you can always set the `Width` of the datagrid column.  Something like `myDataGrid.Columns[0].Width = 100;` should do the trick.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: DataGridColumn.Width property is not `double`, but it's `DataGridLength` and you can not set a digit as it's value.